# How to display username as a value in PHP

Tags: php

I want to know how to display a user's username inside a textbox. I'm doing this because when they edit their settings and update them, it updates their email etc to blank fields in the database:

Here's the code i'd like to change

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" class="required" value="<? echo $row_settings['full_name']; ?>" />
```

I'd like to make the `value = $row_settings['full_name'];'
How can i do this?

ALL CODE:

```
    <?php 
/********************** MYSETTINGS.PHP**************************
This updates user settings and password
************************************************************/
include 'dbc.php';
page_protect();

$err = array();
$msg = array();

if($_POST['doUpdate'] == 'Update')  
{


$rs_pwd = mysql_query("select pwd from users where id='$_SESSION[user_id]'");
list($old) = mysql_fetch_row($rs_pwd);
$old_salt = substr($old,0,9);

//check for old password in md5 format
  if($old === PwdHash($_POST['pwd_old'],$old_salt))
  {
  $newsha1 = PwdHash($_POST['pwd_new']);
  mysql_query("update users set pwd='$newsha1' where id='$_SESSION[user_id]'");
  $msg[] = "Your new password is updated";
  //header("Location: mysettings.php?msg=Your new password is updated");
  } else
  {
   $err[] = "Your old password is invalid";
   //header("Location: mysettings.php?msg=Your old password is invalid");
  }

}

if($_POST['doSave'] == 'Save')  
{
// Filter POST data for harmful code (sanitize)
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $data[$key] = filter($value);
}


mysql_query("UPDATE users SET
      `full_name` = '$data[name]',
      `address` = '$data[address]',
      `tel` = '$data[tel]',
      `user_email` = '$data[user_email]',
      `user_name` = '$data[user]',
      `fax` = '$data[fax]',
      `country` = '$data[country]',
      `website` = '$data[web]'
       WHERE id='$_SESSION[user_id]'
      ") or die(mysql_error());

//header("Location: mysettings.php?msg=Profile Sucessfully saved");
$msg[] = "Profile Sucessfully saved";
 }

$rs_settings = mysql_query("select * from users where id='$_SESSION[user_id]'"); 
?>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.ico">
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate();
   $("#pform").validate();
  });
  </script>

    <title>The Infibox - Edit Profile</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/indexSettings.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {?>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Infibox</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand">|</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/recruitment">My Account</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Settings</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logout</a>
          <?php }

          ?>
  <?php 
if (checkAdmin()) {
/*******************************END**************************/
?>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="admin.php">Admin CP </a>
    <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
          </form>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->


      <p> 
        <?php 
  if(!empty($err))  {
     echo "<div class=\"msg\">";
    foreach ($err as $e) {
      echo "* Error - $e <br>";
      }
    echo "</div>";  
     }
     if(!empty($msg))  {
      echo "<div class=\"msg\">" . $msg[0] . "</div>";

     }
    ?>
      </p>

<!-- Show their details inside the correct box. E.g. their first name they registered with will be shown inside the "First Name" box. Does not occur with passwords. -->
<center>
<div class="wrapper">
<h2 class="title">Edit Profile</h2>
<?php while ($row_settings = mysql_fetch_array($rs_settings)) ?>
<form action="mysettings1.php" method="post" name="myform" id="myform">
<div class="input-group" id="fname">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" class="required" value="<? echo $row_settings['full_name']; ?>" />
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Customer ID</span>
  <input type="text" name="user" class="form-control" maxlength="6" id="web2" value="<? echo $row_settings['user_name']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Email</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_email" id="web3"  value="<? echo $row_settings['user_email']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Add Paypal Email</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tel" id="tel" class="required" value="<? echo $row_settings['tel']; ?>">
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
  <input name="doSave" type="submit" id="doSave" value="Save" class="btn btn-success">
</div>
<hr class="hr" />
<!-- When Changing Password Old Password Must Be Entered + Correct-->
<h2 class="title2">Change Password</h2>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">Old Password</span>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd_old" class="required password" id="pwd_old" >
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">New Password</span>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd_new" class="required password" id="pwd_new" >
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
  <input name="doUpdate" type="submit" id="doUpdate" value="Update" class="btn btn-success">
</div>

</div>
</center>
</form>
<!-- ##################################################################################### -->
<!-- ##################################################################################### -->
</div>
</center>




    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By changing the code to `placeholder="account username"`?

Comment: Before updating with blank values use a check.

Comment: Firstly, John. I have no idea what you're talking about. Placeholder="$full_name" i just want where i put "account username" to be their username.

Comment: ... From what I understand from your question, you're having difficulty with something that looks like you did it correctly about 10 characters earlier in the same line of code? `$row_settings['full_name']` vs `$full_name`... what's going on here? Is there a difference between these two? Where is the `username` that you're after? Is is stored in `$row_settings['full_name']`?

Comment: I lack PHP knowledge.

Comment: MLeFevre, I don't know. I want their username to go in the placeholder box.

Comment: Where is their username? Is it stored in a variable somewhere?

Comment: This is PHP. Their username is stored in a database.

Comment: Yeah I'm a few steps ahead of that. You'll most likely be retrieving user information from the database at this point in the code. Looks like the fullname is being retrieved and displayed with `$row_settings['full_name']` what else is set in `$row_settings`? Guessing your database is MySQL, can you post the query you are using? Maybe it's already being retrieved and is already in something like `$row_settings['username']`. Can't tell with what you've posted.

Comment: Yes it's mySQL - In $row_settings are lots of things, usernames, names, IDs, passwords etc. I've now REMOVED the placeholder because it didn't work anyway, so i need the VALUE to display their $full_name

Comment: Give us some more info: table layout and more php-code.

Comment: @user2961573 surely you already have it, `$row_settings['full_name']`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work @MLeFevre

Comment: If you're trying to learn PHP do not use `mysql_` functions. They're deprecated and may stop working in a future release. Use PDO. Go to the docs on php.net and look at the docs for `mysql_` functions and it will tell you the same.

Comment: So you have no values in your input-fields?

Comment: And maybe change `<?php while ($row_settings = mysql_fetch_array($rs_settings)) ?>` with `<?php $row_settings = mysql_fetch_array($rs_settings); ?>`

Comment: Thank you Gudgip! Works perfectly! <3

Comment: I'm glad it works. I've added it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a while loop:
Change

```
<?php while ($row_settings = mysql_fetch_array($rs_settings)) ?>
```

with

```
<?php $row_settings = mysql_fetch_array($rs_settings); ?>
```